# Cannot log off while using asp.net mvc5 identity, cookies refreshed on posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I'm working on asp.net MVC5 with VS2013, and testing my webapp.
And I found that, when I login my website with (remember me?) checked . I'll sometimes can not logoff correctly.
Then I find in debug tools,that each time when I logoff, It will request a new cookie with Authentication.
How should I do with this situation?

This is the code for LogOff.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This is the problem where I think:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it doesn't always clear the cookie correctly unless you use the following:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```